# Are there some statistics on the political affiliation of NESBs?

Tags: election, parties, australia, statistics, demographics

Non-English speaking background (NESB) is a demographic category often encountered in Australian publications. Are there statistics on the political party affiliation of NESBs (membership or just whom they voted for, say in the last few elections)?

[A book](https://books.google.com/books?id=XWGADAAAQBAJ&pg=PA335) from a decade ago says NESBs are generally "stalwart" Labor supporters, but doesn't get into much details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liang Jiang (2016) studies this using data from the 2013 version of the [Australian Election Study](https://australianelectionstudy.org/) which has been conducted to coincide with federal elections since 1987. While his article gives a detailed analysis of the numbers for 2013, it doesn't extend to AES studies from other years.

Expanding on this, I've looked at the responses from NESBs to the 'party identification' question in the six studies conducted from 2001 to 2016, the results of which are shown below.

[image]

<sub>Liang Jiang (2016) Valence politics and immigrant voting in the
2013 Australian election, Australian Journal of Political Science, 51:3, 418-435, DOI:
[10.1080/10361146.2016.1202890](http://doi.org/10.1080/10361146.2016.1202890)</sub>